BufferedInputStream vs DataInputStream which is faster for sending byte arrays?
My question is straight forward. I made an app with java sockets which can send as many files as you want between two users.However, sometimes transfer can be slow and i think it is because i am sending like this:
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
Instead of this:
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
I also added socket.setTcpNoDelay(true) just in case to make sending faster.
I send byte[] array of size 8192 over the network but it will never get sent in it's original size due to fragmentation and underlying network configuration so i pretty much send as much as OS can handle. Is it possible to make this faster in any way?
I also send byte arrays like this:  (Maybe reading file in some other way than like below with FileInputStream might make things faster?)
    File file = files.get(key);
    byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);

    //read parts of a file and write them to dos
    while ((n = fis.read(buf, 0, (int) Math.min(buf.length, fileSize))) != -1) {
   
        dos.write(buf, 0, n);
        dos.flush();

        if (//if it is aborted while sending) {
            dos.writeBoolean(true);//if it was aborted we will send true
            dos.flush();
            break;
        }


The answer to your real question is to use DataInputStream.readFully() wrapped around a BufferedInputStream. Your comment and code about '//if it is aborted while sending)' don't make any sense whatsoever: if there is an abort during sending you will get an exception rather than proceeding to that line, and the connection will be unusable so you can't send anything else in any case, and if you could it would get mixed up with the prior partial send that got aborted.

Using a BufferedOutputStream and then calling flush after every operation means you're not really doing any buffering, which is what a BufferedOutputStream is meant to be used for. You might as well just use a plain OutputStream. Also, are you aware that DataOutputStream.writeBoolean(true) simply sends a byte value of 1, as a single byte? How do you expect to differentiate that from a byte belonging to the byte array?

A lot simpler would be long numBytesTransferred = Files.newInputStream(file.toPath()).transferTo(dos); Done

@g00se But not for multiple files over the same connection.

@user207421 Why so?

@g00se Because you have to send a length word ahead of the file data, and you better be damn sure you send exactly that many bytes, which can only be the case if you send and count them yourself.

I'm not sure that really makes much difference. If the whole file doesn't get sent, it's going to be an error either way you do it. And either way you're going to know if the whole file wasn't sent. Now, if for some odd reason you don't want to send the whole file (not indicated by the code posted), then the method I outlined is certainly inappropriate.

Basically, no one answered my question. What is Buffered or DataOutputStream? Regarding flushing the boolean, i am sending a flag which states if sending of current file is aborted or not.It works perfectly. Regarding Exceptions if SocketException happens i have to close whole file transfer (which i do not want and that is why i can't throw any exception.)

Basically, no one answered my question. What is Buffered or DataOutputStream? DataOutputStream is an output stream specialized for doing precisely what you are doing, i.e. writing specific tokens to a stream with a data-oriented meaning, as opposed to a continuous sequence of bytes. e.g. "Now I'm writing a byte meaning success, now I want to write a long, etc". Of course, DataOutputStream can also write continuous bytes (as your file transfer) too

BufferedOutputStream is an enhanced stream which can take advantage of bulk writes to its underlying stream. The buffer accumulates the writes in memory and writes them all at once, which is fast, instead of writing all the time to the underlying stream, which is potentially slower.

So if i were to constantly send byte arrays i should then use:  BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());  ?  Also does this mean BufferedOutputStream alone is faster than DataOutputStream even though i have chained them up,like this DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));

Chaining them like that will still get you the benefit of buffering. It would appear you've got a 'mini protocol' of your own going on, in which case, there will be varied types of writes. So hang on to your DataOutputStream for convenience's sake

Thank you for your time to answer @g00se . You helped me a lot

Last question. Is my flushing logic ok then or should i remove it from the loop (the only reason i flush is due to sending a flag to determine whether file is cancelled or not)?

If you want to send right away (although that might not be guaranteed) then yes, flush, otherwise don't.
